# Display current running project in the Listbox control using C# code

Tags: c#, listbox

I am building the projects by making a GUI in the Visual Studio 2010, what i need to do is When i click the Button "Build" in the GUI it will display the current Building/Running Project in the listbox control and after completion of the Build , it will display the status of the Build as "Build Succeeded"  along with it for the Project which is succeeded.

What i have done until now is:-

```
  void fun1()
    {

            FOLDER1 = DRIVE + @":\FolderName";

            LOGFILE1 = FOLDER1 + @"\BUILDLOGS";

            Process msbuild;
            msbuild = new Process();
            DEVENV = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS100COMNTOOLS") + @"..\IDE\devenv.exe";


            var list = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(LOGFILE1);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(item);
            }


            for (int k = 0; k < array.Length; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
                {
                    UpdateProgressBar(j);

                    this.lbl_CurrentProject.Text = "Current Project: " + @" " + array[k];

                    msbuild.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    msbuild.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


                    msbuild.StartInfo.Arguments = FOLDER1 + array[k]  +  @" /out " + LOGFILE1;
                    msbuild.StartInfo.FileName = DEVENV;
                    msbuild.Start();
                    msbuild.WaitForExit();
               }}}

         private void bn_Build_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cb_TheBeast.Checked)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_drive.Text))
            {
                DRIVE = "-";

            }
            else
            {
                DRIVE = cmb_drive.GetItemText(cmb_drive.SelectedItem);
            }
            fun1();
        }
        }
```

My question is how can i display the current running project in the listbox control along with the label "Build Succeeded" along with it for the projects which are succeeded, when i click the build button on the GUI.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you implementing a separate app for this when visual studio can give you all these info ?

Comment: i am implementing in the visual studio only, and i don't get you Sir.

Comment: @kurubaran, What should be done to display list of all items when i click the build button on the GUI to display projects which are succeeded in the building process??